# Validating presence of element by index

Tags: javascript, protractor

So I have a page object function that verifies that a particular error appears on the screen. errorMsg is a selector that has already been defined in a var

```
this.isErrorMessageDisplayed = function() {
        expect(errorMsg.isDisplayed()).to.become(true);
}
```

This function works great. However, I keep running into issues when dealing with elements that have multiple.. For instance if this was defined as a $$ and I wanted to validate all occurrences of them, I tried like this..

```
this.isErrorMessageDisplayed = function() {
        for(i = 0; i < errorMsg.count(); i++){
            expect(errorMsg.get(i).isDisplayed()).to.become(true);
    }
}
```

Why does this not work, however whenever there is just one element that I am trying to identify it works great? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, **protractor runs asynchronously**. Which means when protractor executed a line and went to the next line, it doesn't mean that the line has finished execution. Welcome to the world of Async programming :P

The following code is my recommendation:

```
this.isErrorMessageDisplayed = function () {
    errorMsg.each(function (elem,index) {
       expect(elem.isDisplayed()).toBe(true) 
    });
};
```

Comment: if you aren't going to use the index for anything, why include it in the `.each()` function?  Just keep `elem`

Comment: You guys rock, this worked once I changed it to to.become(true). Thank you all so much

Comment: I just found out something.. this function will still not work because if the count is zero, then it will still pass.

Answer (score 3):

The method `count()` returns a Promise. It cannot be used as an upper bound for your loop. Instead use `$$(...).each` to iterate each element:

```
this.isErrorMessageDisplayed = function() {
  errorMsg.each(e => {
    expect(e.isDisplayed()).to.become(true);
  });
};
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to like the syntax e => { .. is this a correct syntax for JS?

Comment: The arrow function was introduced by ECMAScript 6 and is supported since node 4.4.5. You can replace it with a simple function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like below,

```
this.isErrorMessageDisplayed = function() {
   expect(errorMsg.isDisplayed()).not.to.include(false);
};
```

if you have an array of elements,then isDisplayed will return you with the array of displayed status like `[true,true,true]`.So you need to validate that the array does not contain `false` in it.